# select a column value and the closest/nearest value from it in the same column

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two columns

```
Key,Val
1    31
2    43
3    41
4    100
```

and my expected output is

```
Key,Val,closestVal
1    31    41
2    43    41
3    41    43
4    100   43
```

what can be the simplest sql query to have the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ABS` along with `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.Key, t1.Val, t2.Val AS closestVal,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Key ORDER BY ABS(t1.Val - t2.Val)) rn
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t1.Key <> t2.Key
)

SELECT Key, Val, closestVal
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note: The above demo is for SQL Server, not Teradata.  If `KEY` is a reserved keyword in Teradata, then you will have to escape it if you plan to use it as a column name.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the answer I have another question

Comment: Should I ask over here or should I post it as another question?

Comment: @Mohsin If it be substantially different than what you asked here, then yes, you should open a new question.

Comment: they wont let me ask another question for the next three hours, I just wanted to know what if we want to select two values x1,y1 and the two values closest_x1,closest_y1 with which x1,y1 Euclidean distance or any other distance is minimum.

Comment: here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389523/select-two-values-and-the-two-values-with-which-former-values-have-minimum-dista

Answer (score 1):

I think the most performance query would use `lag()` and `lead()` -- which for some reason Teradata doesn't support directly.  But:

```
select t.*,
       (case when abs(val - min(val) over (order by val rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding)) <
                  abs(val - min(val) over (order by val rows between 1 following and 1 following)
            then min(val) over (order by val rows between 1 preceding and 1 preceding))
            else min(val) over (order by val rows between 1 following and 1 following)
        end) as closest_val
from t;
```

In other words, no subqueries or joins are needed, only window functions.

Comment: what if we want to select two values x1,y1 and the two values closest_x1,closest_y1 with which x1,y1 Euclidean distance or any other distance is minimum

Comment: @Mohsin . . . First, new questions should be asked as *new questions*, not in comments.  Second, you would just put the formulate in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54389523/select-two-values-and-the-two-values-with-which-former-values-have-minimum-dista

Comment: Quite literally your answer has the greatest percentage of SQL keywords I have ever seen :-)