# select two values and the two values with which former values have minimum distance with

Tags: sql, teradata

I have three columns

```
Key, x1,  y1
1    31   34
2    43   40
3    41   44
4    100  40
```

My expected output is:

```
Key, x1,  y2, closest_x1,  closest_y2
1    31   34     43          40
2    43   40     41          44
3    41   44     43          40
4    100  40     41          44
```

what can be the simplest sql query to have the expected output?
Note that both the values x1,y1 are considered while finding out the closest pair

Comment: Which rule do you use to tell which pair is the *closest* one ?

Comment: @GMB can be as simple as abs(x2-x1) + abs(y2-y1) or Euclidean distance

Comment: *Euclidean distance*: do you have geospatial data? Teradata has a geospatial datatype which geospatial indexes...

Answer (score 2):

I think that in line 4 of your expected result the closest values are wrong.
It should be:

```
4   100 40  43  40
```

at least this is the result I get by this:

```
select t.*, tt.x1 closest_x1, tt.y1 closest_y1
from tablename t
inner join tablename tt
on tt.key = (
  select min(key) from tablename where power(x1 - t.x1, 2) + power(y1 - t.y1, 2) = (
    select min(power(x1 - t.x1, 2) + power(y1 - t.y1, 2)) from tablename where key <> t.key
  )
)
order by t.key
```

Results:

```
| key  | x1  | y1  | closest_x1 | closest_y1 |
| ---- | --- | --- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 1    | 31  | 34  | 43         | 40         |
| 2    | 43  | 40  | 41         | 44         |
| 3    | 41  | 44  | 43         | 40         |
| 4    | 100 | 40  | 43         | 40         |
```

Comment: Exactly the same solution I was thinking of. Upvoting.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution for your use case would to self-join the table using a `NOT EXIST` clause to ensure that the record being joined is the closest possible record to the current record.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.x closest_x, t2.y closest_y
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2
    ON t2.k <> t1.k
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM mytable t3
        WHERE
            t3.k <> t1.k
            AND abs(t1.x - t3.x) + abs(t1.y - t3.y) < abs(t1.x - t2.x) + abs(t1.y - t2.y)  
    )
ORDER BY 1;
```

Notes :

- I renamed the table fields to `k`(ey), `x` and `y` for more readbility.
- As suggested by you, this uses Euclidian formula to compute the distance : `abs(x2-x1) + abs(y2-y1)`
- Please note that, if several records are smallest *and* equidistant, multiple rows will be returned.

**[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b8wAMJ2Kmte256DvP9LTsq/2)** :

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.x closest_x, t2.y closest_y
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2
    ON t2.k <> t1.k
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM mytable t3
        WHERE
            t3.k <> t1.k
            AND abs(t1.x - t3.x) + abs(t1.y - t3.y) < abs(t1.x - t2.x) + abs(t1.y - t2.y)  
    )
ORDER BY 1;
```

```
| k   | x   | y   | closest_x | closest_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --------- | --------- |
| 1   | 31  | 34  | 43        | 40        |
| 2   | 43  | 40  | 41        | 44        |
| 3   | 41  | 44  | 43        | 40        |
| 4   | 100 | 40  | 43        | 40        |
```

Comment: I keep thinking the OP wanted the 2D distance, but I can be wrong. Upvoting.

Comment: @TheImpaler : I quite agree with you, but OP gave the euclidian formula in a comment...